How can I convert MediaPipe's normalized screen space coordinates to world space meters?
I'm trying to create a web application in React JS that uses MediaPipe to track facial landmarks and then displays a 3D model in A-Frame, aligned with the face.
MediaPipe provides facial landmark coordinates in screen space, which are normalized values between 0 and 1. However, A-Frame expects world space coordinates in meters for positioning 3D objects.
Mediapipe facelandmark result format : https://ai.google.dev/edge/mediapipe/solutions/vision/face_landmarker/web_js#handle_and_display_results
My goal is to position the 3D model based on the position of specific facial landmarks.
I've tried to convert the screen space coordinates to world space with the below code, but not worked.
// result from mediapipe facelandmark
if (results.faceLandmarks) {
      for (const landmarks of results.faceLandmarks) {
        const _landmark_x = landmarks[164].x * videoRef.current.offsetWidth
        const _landmark_y = landmarks[164].y * videoRef.current.offsetHeight

        const {camera} = AFRAME.scenes[0]
        const body = document.querySelector('body').getBoundingClientRect()
        const x = ((_landmark_x - body.left) / body.width) * 2 - 1
        const y = -((_landmark_y - body.top) / body.height) * 2 + 1

        //vector is the resultant coordinates in the world space
        const vector = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, -1).unproject(camera)
      }
    }

